# session value(login user info) share between two asp.net mvc3 application without use DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have a website(base application) www.abc.com including few sub applications(App A, App B, App C etc). Suppose i have a user who access all application with a single login. Now i need to pass login information base application to sub applications. Suggest me a best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways which i used earlier..

- 1st ...Use session...whenever user login thn store info on any session.and get on sub application.
- 2nd way...get tht login information...make encrypt it...and pass on url..
  like: www.abc.com/ID= Encrypt&Pass=Encrypt
- 3rd way....create a DTO(Data Transfer Object) and store tht credential value...and access DTO on sub application.

Comment: Hello Dipak Jid, Can you give an example for 3rd way?

Comment: Hi..this is DTO class...you have to access this class on your C# code...and create object of this class...and you access this property...now, you can also acess this DTO class on same way on sub appication.

public class ColorModel
    {
        public string ColorName { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceKey { get; set; }
        public string HexCode { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

i think u can get the username in main applications using

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);
```

In other subapplications u can get the useridentity using

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: start a new website "Asp.Net Forms Website".. it will generate a code for the main application with a master page which handles Login using an OpenAuth.dll which is an industry standard. u should see the code in the Account Folder.